# Py2app: Operation not permitted

Tags: python, macos, pygame, py2app

I want to create an application called 'dodgeball' and I have my main script (which uses pygame), and my setup.py script. I need an image named ball.bmp that I need as well.

Inside my setup.py script I have the following code:

    from setuptools import setup

```
APP = ['dodgeball.py']
DATA_FILES = ["ball.bmp"]
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Whenever I try to make the application using the following stuff in Terminal:

```
python setup.py py2app
```

everything works up to

```
*** creating application bundle: dodgeball ***
```

then it returns an error:

```
error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/**********/Desktop/Dodgeball/dist/dodgeball.app/Contents/MacOS/dodgeball'
```

If it helps, I'm on Mac OS X  El Capitan (10.11). I'm aware that El Capitan, like any Apple update, will have new software and features that may break stuff like this.

**QUESTION**

How do I fix this error and then allow py2app to make a fully functionable app?

Comment: Maybe you should try running your command with `sudo`

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't have the error anymore, but now when I try to open it it says "dodgeball error". :(

Comment: see also https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6987

Answer (score 8):

After I upgraded my operating system to OS X El Capitan (10.11.2), I got similar error when packaging my app using py2app:

```
*** creating application bundle: MyApp ***
error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/jake/work/my-app/dist/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp'
```

I did some research and found a solution: 1) disable SIP; 2) remove restricted file flag on Python.framework. It worked for me.

### Disable SIP

1. Restart your Mac.
2. Before OS X starts up, hold down Command+R and keep it held down until you see an Apple icon and a progress bar. Release. This boots you into Recovery.
3. From the Utilities menu, select Terminal.
4. At the prompt type the following:

   ```
   csrutil status
   csrutil disable
   reboot
   ```

You can re-enable SIP by following the above steps, but using:

```
csrutil enable
```

References:

- http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/
- http://www.macworld.com/article/2986118/security/how-to-modify-system-integrity-protection-in-el-capitan.html

### Remove Restricted File Flag

```
sudo chflags -R norestricted /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
```

As it's mentioned in https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6987

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. Instead of running

```
python setup.py py2app
```

I tried

```
python3 setup.py py2app
```

and it worked just fine. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the system provided py2app. Running this fixed the issue for me:

```
pip install --user --ignore-installed py2app
```

(I'm usually wary of things that require me to disable System Integrity Protection)

Comment: This is the better solution. I'd prefer not to disable SIP. This worked great for me.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution: Install with `-U` flag!

Since all of you will have installed py2app already, start by uninstalling it.

```
pip3 uninstall py2app
```

After this point, it's **crucial** that you reinstall it using the `-U` flag!

```
pip3 install -U py2app
py2applet --make-setup YourApp.py
python3 setup.py py2app -A
```

Look in your `dist/` folder, there should now be a runnable application.

Then you can rebuild it using `python3 setup.py py2app`

**Verified on OS X Catalina, Mojave, Big Sur**

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't happen if you build and install your own [py2app](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/py2app/) rather than depending on the OS-bundled one.

Inside your virtualenv, install Mercurial (if needed), then:

```
pip install hg+https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/py2app/
```

`py2app` should then work without issue.

Comment: Edited my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error on my Mac, version Sierra 10.12. My inspiration came from @Nicholas Riley's answer.

**The context of my issue:**

- building a simple app using pandas and easygui
- working in a virtualenv
- setup.py was already generated by running `$ py2applet --make-setup MyApplication.py`
- py2app was installed globally, but not yet in my virtualenv
- virtualenv was not active

**My solution:**

activate the virtualenv

`Spievats-MacBook-Pro:EasyGuiTest user$ source bin/activate`

install py2app in the virtualenv

`(EasyGuiTest) Spievats-MacBook-Pro:EasyGuiTest brady$ pip install py2app`

run py2app again

`(EasyGuiTest) Spievats-MacBook-Pro:EasyGuiTest brady$ python setup.py py2app -A`

This worked perfectly! I hope it helps someone else.